# master-master replication or master slave replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

We have right now one server with a database.
A device and a website are accessing that database causing load

What I want is to create two servers master-slave where master databases are replicated to slave but slave have some databases that must not be in master database.

Is it possible to do it using master-slave replication or using master-master replication?

Comment: Sure it's possible with master-slave. Check out the options `--binlog-ignore-db` and `--replicate-wild-ignore-table`, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do not want writes to be replicated from A to B then A better be slave of B, master.

again, to complicate things you can use master-master with replication filters but let's not get there if you do-not wish to.

That said, writing on slave is sort of risky business where you're going to "accidentally" write on databases being replicated from master and that's not good!
As long as you're making sure you're only writing to slave-only databases it should be fine. You should choose to create dedicated users for such activity.
You might also want to wonder:
- What about backups of master data?
- What about backups of slave data?

just saying... but yea to answer your question go with master-slave.

Comment: But isn't it going to create a conflict ? Because I read that any changes in slave should be synced with master else it can cause errors

Comment: or putting binlog-ignore-db in master will ignore those db's in slave! also I have heard that master master replication is very dangerous to use!

Comment: 1st comment: Very first thing is you should not change on "slave" when you're calling it a slave. If you're intended to make changes on slave then either it's wrong or you want to make it master. Btw share the source which says "changes on slave should be synced with master"

Comment: 2nd comment: Replication filters are to be used carefully... Read the working of replication filters on documentation and then compare binlog-ignore-db and replicate-do-db !!
- It's too complex to fix data discrepancies while you write on both masters and hence it should be avoided.

Comment: But when I'm making a database in slave that is not in master isn't it a wrong approach as well? if both the approaches are not good then what should I do? here is the link http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44431/mysql-replication-slave-update

Comment: Question is why are you making database on slave? Let's decide the requirement first.

Comment: because I have two things connected to the same database causing load!  one is the device and the other is the web, there are some databases that both the device and web are accessing but there are some databases that only the web can access like user information also there may be some databases only device wants and not the web

Comment: In that case first make sure queries are well optimized and then the server. You can split read-write traffic between master and slave.